# Trying to vertically center link with text and image

Tags: html, css, menu, vertical-alignment

I'm working on a project of a website where in the menu I have to vertically align the link that have two parts: one image and a description. The aim is this:
[image]
But I just can do this:

```css
li {  
 display: inline;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

a.itens:link {
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a.itens:visited {
 color: #000;
}

.menu {
 border: 5px solid #EC771A;
 font-size: 20;
 font-family: Oxygen;
 height: 52px;
    width: 909px;
}

ul {
 margin-top: 4px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

div.4 {
 width: 168px;
 height: 52px;
}

div.ljuntesse {
 width: 28px;
 height: 52px;
}

div.tjuntesse {
 width: 140px;
 height: 52px;
}

.ljuntesse, tjuntesse {
 display: inline;
}

li.5 {
 padding-bottom: 17px;
}


.lampada {
 display: inline;
 width: 25px;
 height: 41px;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="menu">
   <ul>
    <b>
     <li><a class="itens" href=#menu>Home</a></li>

     <li><a class="itens" href=#Projetos><img class="lampada" src="images/parceiros.png">Parceiros</a></li>

     <li><a class="itens" href=#LinksUteis><img class="lampada" src="images/links.png">Links Uteis</a> </li> 

     <div class="4">
      <a class="itens" href=#Blog>
       <div class="ljuntesse">
        <img class="lampada" src="images/juntesse.png">
       </div>
       <div class="tjuntesse">
        <li>Junte-se a Nós</a></li>
       </div>
     </div>

     <a class="itens" href=#Contactos><img class="lampada" src="images/contactos.png"><li class="5">Contactos</li></a>
    </b>
   </ul>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I have three tries:

- The first that's just the image with the text aligned with the end of the image;
- The second where I tried to insert divs and finally insert different margins, but as long as both are inside one div It just passed one line down;
- The third where I tried to change the order of the first try to separate the two things: image and text.

Does anyone know how to align the menu like in the image?

Comment: Mukesh I've seen your edtion and I really thing it's now better but do I have to do anything to stay with this version or everyone can already see as you eddited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:middle;` to `.lampada`. You make it more complex so i have also update the html code.

```css
li {  
 display: inline;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

a.itens:link {
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a.itens:visited {
 color: #000;
}

.menu {
 border: 5px solid #EC771A;
 font-size: 20;
 font-family: Oxygen;
 height: 52px;
    width: 909px;
}

ul {
 margin-top: 4px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

div.4 {
 width: 168px;
 height: 52px;
}

div.ljuntesse {
 width: 28px;
 height: 52px;
}

div.tjuntesse {
 width: 140px;
 height: 52px;
}

.ljuntesse, tjuntesse {
 display: inline;
}

li.5 {
 padding-bottom: 17px;
}


.lampada {
 display: inline;
 width: 25px;
 height: 41px;
   vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="menu">
  <ul>    
    <li><a class="itens" href=#menu>Home</a></li>

    <li><a class="itens" href=#Projetos><img class="lampada" src="images/parceiros.png">Parceiros</a></li>

    <li><a class="itens" href=#LinksUteis><img class="lampada" src="images/links.png">Links Uteis</a> </li>
      <li><a class="itens" href=#Blog><img class="lampada" src="images/juntesse.png">Junte-se a Nós</a></li>
      <li><a class="itens" href=#Contactos><img class="lampada" src="images/contactos.png">Contactos</a></li>
      
  </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow! Headache's over! Thanks very much!